# How to set artifact id and other info programmatically using maven invoker

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, maven-plugin, maven-invoker-plugin

I'm trying to create a maven project programmatically by running a java application. In the application, I have set the pom file as:

```
request.setPomFile(new File(thePomFile));
request.setGoals( Collections.singletonList( "archetype:generate" ) );
```

This is a pom file with archetype info that I want to use since I have my own project structure.

Two questions:

1. I get an error saying "No archetype defined. Using maven-archetype-quickstart (org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:1.0)"; why is this even though I provided the archetype pom file?
2. I also get 
   "[WARNING] Property groupId is missing. Add -DgroupId=someValue
   [WARNING] Property artifactId is missing. Add -DartifactId=someValue
   [WARNING] Property package is missing. Add -Dpackage=someValue"; how to I supply these information to the request. The api doesn't seem to have it.

I tried looking up the api docs, and other stackoverflow questions but couldn't find anything close to this. Thank you!

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why are you creating maven projects on the fly? And sorry, I don't have an answer for your question. Never even thought of that :)

Comment: Quite hard to answer without minimal working example. Does it work without calling invoker?

Comment: Have you already created and installed the archetype as explained in [Maven docs](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-creating-archetypes.html)?

Comment: @JorgeCampos I need it for some tests but don't want to copy all the directories and dependencies that are required to start my project. Let me know if there is a better way.

Comment: @RobertScholte creating an archetype through the command line works.

Comment: What kind of tests are you talking about?

Comment: @JorgeCampos, we have a fragment that needs to keep on running for us to create new tests as well as test various differences in that fragment. Because there are many variations/permutations, I want to create a project that can be loaded with different configurations before the test start. It might be hard to explain without actually showing but if that makes sense. Anyway, I figured out a solution. Sorry about the late response!

Comment: No problem. Though what you explained seems like you actually need a way to register something on the fly, you don't actually need to create a project you could use the concept of adding plugins to your code base. But since it makes sence to you to do that its ok! cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to supply the information in point 2, by answering the question in the first place.

In the request itself, you need to do:

```
request.setGoals(Collections.singletonList("archetype:generate -DgroupId=.....");
```

Then if you look at the api docs, there is a command line builder that I didn't notice before: https://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-invoker/apidocs/index.html

```
MavenCommandLineBuilder mavenCmd = new MavenCommandLineBuilder();
```

Set the necessary configurations like base directory, path to maven executable etc to this mavenCmd.

Then, you can send your previously created request to it, like:

```
Commandline result = mavenCmd.build(request);
```

To answer my first point, I ended up removing setting pom itself because I was fetching it remotely and mentioned the archetype in the command I sent to mavenCmd. There might be a better way but this worked for me and I'm good with it.